# How to connect a signal from a thread to a slot?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

What I simply want to do is connect a signal inside a thread to a slot in the main thread to handle UI changes.

This is basically the current state of my thread, nothing fancy but it's just for testing purposes atm:

```
// synchronizer.h
class Synchronizer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Synchronizer();

signals:
    void newConnection(std::wstring id);

private:
    QTimer timer;

private slots:
    void synchronize();
}

// synchronizer.cpp
Synchronizer::Synchronizer()
{
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(synchronize()));
    timer.start();
}

void Synchronizer::synchronize()
{
    emit newConnection(L"test");
}
```

And here's how my MainWindow looks:

```
// mainwindow.h
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Synchronizer synchronizer;

private slots:
    void addConnection(std::wstring id);
}

// mainwindow.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(&synchronizer, SIGNAL(newConnection(std::wstring)),
            this, SLOT(addConnection(std::wstring)));
    QThread *thread = new QThread;
    // The problems starts here?
    synchronizer.moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::addConnection(std::wstring id)
{
    // Add a new connection to QListWidget
    ui->connectionList(QString::fromStdWString(id));
}
```

If I remove there lines:

```
synchronizer.moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();
```

everything seems to work as expected, that is a new item is added every second to a QListWidget but as soon as I move the synchronizer object to thread it simply stops working. I'd presume it has something to do with the connect context but I'm not really sure how something like this should be achieved as I'm quite new to Qt.

Comment: You probably need to do the connect after the synchronizer.moveToThread(thread); or use the Qt::QueuedConnection parameter in the connect.

Comment: I copied your code into my application and it works fine. Maybe I'm not reading the question properly?

Comment: I'm not sure why it worked for you as I already found the culprit and posted it below so I will guess that it's due to the fact that I have C++11 enabled on my project. If it's not due to that, than I'm just as confused as you might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the in this case was simply the fact that I am using std::wstring as an argument in the signal without registering the type first and after adding the following line `qRegisterMetaType<std::wstring>("std::wstring");` to the code, everything worked as expected.

If I would have read the output console more carefully I would have solved the problem without too much hassle as it was clearly stated that:
`QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'std::wstring'`

So simply speaking, read the compiler output and don't be stupid like me :)

Comment: You mentioned it works if you comment the moveToThread and start out. That was wrong information, then?

Comment: No, it did work when I commented out the two lines but it wasn't in a separate thread at that point and worked on the same (main) thread as the MainWindow object. So my guess would be that argument queuing applies when you try to pass an argument out of the thread and is not needed while you work on the same thread, most likely resulting in simple local method calls without any fancy queuing.

Comment: I would not understand how that is related to registering a meta type.

Comment: [Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) it states: `With queued connections, the parameters must be of types that are known to Qt's meta-object system, because Qt needs to copy the arguments to store them in an event behind the scenes.`. And when using `Qt::AutoConnection`, it will use queued connection when signaling across threads. `If the signal is emitted from a different thread than the receiving object, the signal is queued, behaving as Qt::QueuedConnection. Otherwise, the slot is invoked directly, behaving as Qt::DirectConnection.`